# Be biased towards a svm decision in libsvm

Tags: libsvm

I have a skewed data set: 15% positive and 85% negative. I need to create two svms from libsvm:

1 - that can make the correct predictions for positive data tuples all the time (or max number of times possible) 
and

2 - correct predictions for negative data tuples all the time (or max number of times possible).

I tried using F-score as a method giving a range of weights. But recall for positive tuples becomes zero all the time, therefore it is not giving proper results.

How can I do that with libsvm? Is there a method that I can use to calculate weights for the svms to achieve this?

Comment: Too many people try to do impossible things with incomplete data. Are you *sure* the samples contain the information which is necessary to produce the outcome you seek?

Comment: @tripleee Yes I am sure about that. Isn't there any way to do this?